# Retornar para main() após usar método start()

Tags: java, thread, concorrência

Após executar o comando `gerenciador.start()`, meu programa não retorna para a função `main`, e não imprime a mensagem ***acabou***. Ele simplesmente executa o comando que falei. Alguém sabe por que isso acontece?

```
  public class Principal 
{
    private static long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Fila sharedLine = new Fila();

        Elevador elev = new Elevador(sharedLine);
        Esquiador gerenciador = new Esquiador(sharedLine);

        gerenciador.start();
        //elev.start();
        System.out.println("acabou");
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("It took " + (int)(((endTime - startTime)/1000)/60) + " milliseconds");
    }
}



public class Esquiador extends Thread 
{
     Fila sharedLine;
     static boolean todosEntraram = false;
    //String filaQuePertenco;
    //int idEsquiador;

    public Esquiador(Fila fila) 
    {
        super("Esquiador");
        sharedLine = fila;
        //filaQuePertenco = filaQ;
        //idEsquiador=id;

    }

    public void run()
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {

            try 
             {
                System.out.println("O esquiador está dormindo.");
                Thread.sleep(500);
             } 

            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Esquiadores esquis = new Esquiadores(i);

            //System.out.println("O esquiador "+ esquis.idEsquiador+ " entrou em seu 'run'");
            //while(true)
            //{
                    //política do esquiador para decidir em qual fila ele irá entrar

                    //printando o tamanho de cada fila.
                    System.out.println("O esquiador "+esquis.idEsquiador+" chegou para ingressar numa fila.");
                    System.out.println("Tamanho LS"+sharedLine.elementosLS.size());
                    System.out.println("Tamanho RS"+sharedLine.elementosRS.size());
                    System.out.println("Tamanho LT"+sharedLine.elementosLT.size());
                    System.out.println("Tamanho RT"+sharedLine.elementosRT.size());
                    System.out.println("Esquiador operando ...");


                    if(sharedLine.elementosLS.size()<2*sharedLine.elementosLT.size() && sharedLine.elementosLS.size()<2*sharedLine.elementosRT.size() && sharedLine.elementosLS.size()<sharedLine.elementosRS.size())
                    {
                        //this.filaQuePertenco = "LS";
                        //System.out.println("add ls");
                        sharedLine.adicionaFilaLS(esquis);

                        //printando elementos da fila LS

                    }

                    else if(sharedLine.elementosRS.size()<2*sharedLine.elementosLT.size() && sharedLine.elementosRS.size()<2*sharedLine.elementosRT.size() && sharedLine.elementosRS.size()<=sharedLine.elementosLS.size())
                    {
                        //this.filaQuePertenco = "RS";
                        //System.out.println("add rs");
                        sharedLine.adicionaFilaRS(esquis);

                        //printando elementos da fila RS
                    }

                    else if(sharedLine.elementosLT.size()<=sharedLine.elementosRT.size())
                    {
                        //this.filaQuePertenco = "LT";
                        //System.out.println("add lt");
                        sharedLine.adicionaFilaLT(esquis);

                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        //this.filaQuePertenco = "RT";
                        //System.out.println("add rt");
                        sharedLine.adicionaFilaRT(esquis);
                    }

                    System.out.println("Situação das filas após a operação:");
                    System.out.println("Tamanho LS"+sharedLine.elementosLS.size());
                    System.out.println("Tamanho RS"+sharedLine.elementosRS.size());
                    System.out.println("Tamanho LT"+sharedLine.elementosLT.size());
                    System.out.println("Tamanho RT"+sharedLine.elementosRT.size());
            //}
        }
        Esquiador.todosEntraram = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: O que é `gerenciador.start();`???

Comment: Existe uma classe que eu criei e coloquei um método run() nela. Esse gerenciador.start() eu chamei após instanciar um objeto da classe que falei, com o intuito de criar uma thread e executar o método run .

Comment: Coloque ela também na pergunta! [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/170956/edit)

Comment: Pronto, cara. Completei a Classe principal e Adicionei a classe que lhe disse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A execução está retornando para o método `main`, mas diferente do que você imagina. A linha "acabou" é impressa antes da primeira iteração da thread `Esquiador`.

Acho que você estava esperando que o método `start` executasse o método `run` da thread e somente depois voltasse para o `main`, contudo, o propósito de uma thread é justamente executar em paralelo, ao mesmo tempo.

Neste caso, como você força uma pausa logo no início do `for` da thread, isto faz com que quase que invariavelmente, o método `main` termine antes do primeiro `sleep`.

Para aguardar a finalização de uma thread, use o método `join`, assim:

```
gerenciador.start();
gerenciador.join(); //somente continue depois que a thread finalizar
```

Além deste equívoco, há diversos outros problemas ou pelo menos problemas em potencial:

1. A exibição do tempo está dividindo o tempo que já está em milissegundos por 1000 e por 60, portanto o resultado será em horas, não ms.
2. Suas threads parecem estar compartilhando objetos e executando operações sem sincronização e sem mecanismos de proteção contra problemas de concorrência. Em sua implementação final, você deve se assegurar de que cada vez que você altera um objeto, isto ocorra de forma atômica.
3. É um pouco difícil de entender a intenção exata do código, mas se a ideia original era ter 30 esquiadores, a implementação está completamente errada. Você tem que criar 30 threads e não uma thread contendo um laço executado 30 vezes sequencialmente.

Comment: Isso, a minha intenção era criar 30 esquiadores. No caso , pra eu criar 30 threads, teria que instanciar todas elas na main, por exemplo dentro de um laço de repetição ?

Comment: Minha intenção era criar as 30 threads mesmo. No caso eu teria que instanciá-las na main, com um laço de repetição dentro do qual eu daria 30 starts ?

Comment: @RenandaSilvaAlves Isso mesmo. Coloca elas numa lista, dê 30 starts e DEPOIS 30 joins para esperar todas terminarem.

Comment: Meu amigo, muito obrigado ! Se não fosse esse seu conselho, eu iria tirar um belo 0 amanhã ! Complicado entregar um projeto pra disciplina de programação concorrente sem ter concorrência de threads neh kk. Abraço !!